# Check if data is already localized in GlobalData.xml

Tags: c1-cms

Related:
[Composite C1 console edit button available for non translated data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18869005/composite-c1-console-edit-button-available-for-non-translated-data)

In Composite C1 2.1.1 we use static C# data which is localizable, however the edit button is visible before the data is translated. One answer in the related question is to change the TreeDefinitions\GlobalData.xml, though i would like to know if it is possible to check in the <Actions> element or its parent whether the data has already been localized?

I can not find any good details on this, only whether to show/hide all localizable data but not showing the selected piece of data in the tree.

Comment: Any chance you will be upgrading to a recent release? 2.1.1 is close to three years old and my memory on this is vague.

Comment: Yes, there is a plan to upgrade to 4.1. But also this version has the same error so the question still remains only with a newer version.